# zero-knowledge proof of disjunctive statements (OR proofs)

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I know there are standard ways to prove disjunctive statements about discrete logs, e.g. [OR proof](ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/crypto/publications/CamSta97b.pdf). But are there similar approaches for other class of language? For example, how can one go about proving either $G_1$ or $G_2$ has a Hamiltonian path (without leaking which one)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [CDS94](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48658-5_19.pdf)-technique for that. Suppose you have two zero-knowledge proof systems $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, both of which consist of three messages: a commitment $com$, a (public-coin) challenge $ch$, and a response $r$. And suppose you want to prove the OR of both claims, meaning that you can generate a valid proof for (wlog.) $\sigma_1$ for any challenge even after generating the commitment, but in order to generate a valid proof for $\sigma_2$ you must get the challenge first and compute the commitment from there. So you have essentially one degree of freedom in the choice of $(ch_1, ch_2)$, *i.e.*, one is fixed beforehand but you want to hide which one. The clue is to get a new challenge $ch'$ from the verifier and guarantee that $(ch_1, ch_2, ch')$ satisfies a suitable relation, for instance sum-to-zero. So the proof system for $\sigma_1$-OR-$\sigma_2$ looks like this:

- preprocessing by the prover: compute $com_2, ch_2, rsp_2$ for a random $ch_2$
- prover sends commitment: $com_1, com_2$
- verifier sends challenge: $ch'$
- prover computes $ch_1 \leftarrow ch' - ch_2$ and uses this to complete $\sigma_1$
- prover sends response: $(ch_1, rsp_1), (ch_2, rsp_2)$
- verifier verifies that $(com_1, ch_1, rsp_1)$ is valid, that $(com_2, ch_2, rsp_2)$ is valid, and that $ch_1 + ch_2 + ch' = 0$

You can use $\sum_i ch_i = ch'$ for OR-proofs consisting of any number of claims. However, in some cases you want to prove more specific facts such as "$t$ out of these $n$ claims are true". In this case, you want to use Shamir's secret sharing and exchange the sum-to-zero relation for a polynomial of degree $n+1-t$: this guarantees that all $n-t$ degrees of freedom for choosing $ch_i$ must be used up by the false claims.

The CDS-94 technique applies to any zero-knowledge proof system that follows this three-pass public coin structure. Schnorr's protocol for proving discrete logarithm knowledge is just one particular case of that structure.

[CDS94](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48658-5_19.pdf): Cramer, Ronald, Ivan Damgård, and Berry Schoenmakers. "Proofs of partial knowledge and simplified design of witness hiding protocols." CRYPTO 1994.

Comment: Can you give an example for the "t out of n claims" or a reference?

Comment: The CDS'94 paper referenced above treats this case extensively.