# How would I prove a number is not within a range?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

This would be the opposite of a rangeproof.

For example, I wanted to prove that my number was not between 0 and 200 in zero knowledge?

On a separate note: how would I prove that I hold a number, but it is not a specific number x ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by combining two range proof with an OR proof.

Specifically, given a commitment $c$ to a secret number $x$, you would prove the statement: ($x > 200$) OR ($x < 0$). Each of the two statements can be proven using any standard $\Sigma$-protocol for range proofs (see e.g. my answers [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42019/zero-knowledge-proof-for-sign-of-message-value/42029#42029) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54007/prove-integer-is-within-the-interval-a-b?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and there are [standard methods](https://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/papers/crypto94.pdf) to construct a $\Sigma$-protocol for the OR of two statements given a $\Sigma$-protocol for each of the statements. You can find simple explanations about how this works by reading Section 3.5.1.2 of [my PhD thesis](https://www.di.ens.fr/~couteau/thesis.pdf).

For your second question, the usual strategy is as follows: you have a homomorphic commitment (e.g. a Pedersen commitment) to a value $v$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime, and you want to prove that it is not equal to $x$. To do so, compute $m = (v-x)^{-1} \bmod p$ and commit to it. Note that $v-x$ has an inverse modulo $p$ if and only if $v \neq x$. Then, prove that the committed value $m$ was correctly constructed by proving that $m\cdot (v-x) = 1$, using any standard $\Sigma$-protocol for proving multiplicative relations between committed values.