# How to show that Cx is a commitment to a integer of length lm

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

With reference to Jan Camenisch and Anna Lysyanskaya's paper [*A Signature Scheme with Efficient Protocols*](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/lysyanskaya/cl02b.pdf), in [proceedings of SCN 2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-36413-7_20), I need some help to understand How to verify that $C_x$ is a commitment to an integer of length $l_m$.

$$C_x = g^x * h^r$$, where $x$ is the secret and  $r$ is the randomness; $g$ and $h$ are known parameters

Comment: This looks very much like a standard Pedersen commitment (assuming the operations are within a finite group where the discrete log is hard).

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove knowledge of an opening $(x,r)$ to a Pedersen commitment, such that $x$ belongs to the range $[0,2^{l_m}]$. Such a proof is called a range proofs, and many methods exist, using bit-decomposition (commit to $x$ bit by bit, prove that the sum of the $x_i\cdot 2^i$ is indeed $x$, and prove that each committed value is a bit) or square decomposition techniques over hidden order groups. I discussed some of these methods in several answers, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54007/prove-integer-is-within-the-interval-a-b?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42019/zero-knowledge-proof-for-sign-of-message-value/42029#42029). The latest state-of-the-art method for range proofs is [Bulletproof](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf), which achieves relatively impressive efficiency guarantees, to the point that it's actually used in several real-world applications (e.g. the cryptocurrencies Monero and Mimblewimble, among others).

Answer (score 0):

The only strategy I know is to use one commitment per bit. Then you can prove that all the commitments corresponding to the $i^{th}$ bit for $i> l_m$ contains zero.

Comment: I don't get if what you are proposing is making any use of the question's $C_x$.